# bootstrap Validator issue when i edit form

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form and I used field validator on it and its working fine but when i open form in edit mode and empty field and press save bootstrap Validator not works.

Below is the validator code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#frmSpecialtyDetail')
        .bootstrapValidator({
            message: 'This value is not valid',
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                ShortName: {
                    group: '.col-md-6',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Short Name is required'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Here I am using bootstrapvalidator.js

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the original BootstrapValidator website, this is the code you have to use in order for the form to submit once it succeeds with the validation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(form)
    .bootstrapValidator({
        ... options ...
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            // ... Process the result ...
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

In your case I'd do something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frmSpecialtyDetail')
    .bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            ShortName: {
                group: '.col-md-6',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Short Name is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            // ... Process the result ...
        }, 'json');
    });
 });
```

Hope that helps.

Source: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/ajax-submit/

Comment: I have not this issue my issue is when I open form validation works but when i open same form in edit mode validation not works and I also didn't get any exception. Any help??